# Adding own data to ArcGIS.com javascript template and hosting locally

Tags: javascript, viewer, arcgis-online

ArcGIS.com has a basic viewer javascript template where you can create a map using ArcGIS.com and then download the files/template to be hosted locally.  I won't be able to upload my data to ArcGIS.com so I want to know how hard it is to add my data to the template to be hosted locally.  I currently have the template downloaded and hosted locally with an ArcGIS.com basemap.  I would like to add my own ArcGIS Server map services to it.

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS Server? Then you can run it locally.

Comment: you don't have to have your data uploaded to arcgis.com to have it added to the map you just have to use the add layer from web option, that of course, would require ArcGIS Server as Mapperz suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do have ArcGIS Server.  Three follow-up questions.  1. If I add the map service from web option, I have to share it to generate the application.  Does that expose it to the public?  2. The ArcGIS Server map service is not exposed to the public, can it still be added to ArcGIS.com?  3. If I want to add/remove data from the application, I just have to edit the map on ArcGIS.com and it will be reflected in the application automatically?

Comment: @Steve According to my knowledge: question 1 & question 2 it depends which subscription you have (two type free and organizational) for free subscription your data is publicly available (If you share your web app publicly) question 3. Yes it will update automatically.

Comment: when you say "not exposed to the public" do you mean you have identity manager set, which requires a user to enter a username and password to see the service? Otherwise, anybody with the url to your app will have view access to your service.

Comment: Thanks again for the responses.  Craig, I meant its an intranet url.  http://localhost...can it still be added to arcgis.com?

Comment: Ok after playing with it, I see I can add from localhost to ArcGIS online.  Thanks for the responses.  Cleared up a lot!